# Updating Monero GUI after a few years (!)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, mymonero, monero-forks

I bought a little XMR years ago back when the most up-to-date GUI was v0.11.1.0 (running a local node on MacOS). I hadn't touched my XMR balance since and just finally decided to try to update to the newest GUI, so I downloaded v0.17.1.8 (for MacOS). The new GUI shows my balance, but seems unable to start the daemon or connect to the network. I've seen some users mentioning that if you're running a local node, the integrated daemon will first have to convert your database to a new version (as a part of the upgrade process), and that the GUI will show that it's disconnected during this time. I've seen some users suggest that this period can take 5-10 minutes before the database conversion has completed and the GUI connects back to the daemon. However, I've been waiting for a couple of hours now, and I still see no progress and no ability to connect to the network or start the daemon. I'm wondering if updating from such an old GUI version to the newest version would significantly increase this database conversion wait time? I'm unable to deduce whether I should be doing some other sort of troubleshooting at this point or whether I simply need to let the GUI run for many hours because I waited so long to upgrade. If anyone can offer any suggestions it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I'd say let it run.  Or better, use the CLI version so you can run the daemon alone and watch it.  Don't fear the command line (terminal)

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue? If not, please see the linked guide.